# How to include css files for api routers in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express and handlebars. The problem is the pages which have urls like http://localhost:5000/api/posts does not include css files. However, routers like http://localhost:5000 or http://localhost:5000/register work completely fine.

directories

```
app
-server.js
-routes
  -api
    -posts.js
-public
  -css
  -images
-views
  -layout
    -main.handlebars
  -posts.handlebars
```

in server.js . (only important part)

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));
app.get('/register', (req, res) => res.render('register'));

app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
```

Since I did include `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in server.js, I thought there should not be any problem with the static files.

However, in main.handlebars `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">` does not work. On the other hand, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">` did work.
Moreover, it also worked if I changed the  `app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));` to `app.use('/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));` Are there any other ways to solve this problem if I don't want to change the routes here?

The error when css is not included was `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/api/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.` However, I do not know how to make the public becomes the default path . for static files since I already included  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your css file use `href="/css/main.css"`. What you are using is relative path, check network tab in browser debug. It will load `http://localhost:5000/api/css/main.css` not `http://localhost:5000/css/main.css`.

Btw if you want to build a RESTful api, I don't think it should response a css file.

Comment: @KittichoteKamalapirat the same, just change to `/images/example.png` . URL with / will start from host and URL without / will start from current URL.